# why were the product images not showing up in magento front end

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am new to Magento and I am browsing through it....I have installed 1.7 community Edition on localhost.

I have added s product and I have added images to the product .But, the images for the product are not showing up in front-end....I have cleared cache but it didn't work...Does any one know what to do?

I also got another problem. When I click on this product with no image,it takes to the product page but page doesn't have any styles...This is not happening with the products from sample data

Comment: are your folders readable? And tell us if you run your localhost on a windows-machine.

Comment: Yes I am running on localhost on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha...Got it....I need to select radio buttons for images for each store view...and I got them in the front end. This feature is highly un-intuitive....I hope they find a better way in future versions

Answer (score 4):

Try this -- Go to Admin panel > Catalog > Manage Products > click on the product in the list > Product Information > Images -- you can upload product images here. If you have already uploaded the image click on the radio button under the titles 'Base Image', 'small image', 'thumbnail'. and then click on save.

For applying styles to the product page go to  Product Information > Design & select your theme from 'Custom Design' & 'Page Layout' you want.

Comment: I did that but images don't show up....I can see thumbnails but I am not able to see the images in the place holders